# Why my code does not produce the pattern in the 2nd loop?

Tags: python, loops, design-patterns, pattern-matching

Why does my code not work in the 2nd iteration? I want to give input in row = 3 or 5 or x, and then I expect it to produce the following output pattern:

```
#When row = 3

1|. . #  
2|. ##  
3|###
```

Please note that the number of "." will be opposite to the number of "#"

The `i` loop prints a new line, the `j` loop prints "#", and the `k` loop prints "."

```
row = 3 

for i in range(1, row + 1):
    for j in range(1, i + 1):
        for k in range(1, (row - i) + 1):
            print(".", end= "")
        print("#", end="")
    print("")
```

Comment: hi, download pycharm and use debug. Its will be really helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your k loop runs too many times to do what you want after the first iteration.

However I think this does what you want, hope it helps:

```
row = 3

n_hash = 0
n_dots = row
for i in range(row):
    print(f'{i+1}|{n_dots * "."}{n_hash * "#"}')
    n_dots -= 1
    n_hash += 1
```